# document.referrer if statement is not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

document.referrer conditional always shows the former statement as true, but it shouldn't be

```
if (document.referrer == "https://parks.com/parks/falls" || "https://parks.com/parks/events/falls" || "https://parks.com/parks/promotions/falls" || "https://parks.com/parks/go-green/falls" || "https://parks.com/parks/info/falls") { 
console.log("Don't Show Modal - coming from a Falls page", document.referrer);
} else {
console.log("Show Modal - coming from some other Page", document.referrer);
$( window ).on('load', function() {
   console.log("modal firing");
   $('#modal').modal({
   backdrop: 'static',
   keyboard: false,
   show: true
   });
});
}
```

when a user enters the web page from a Falls page, the modal should not show. if a user enters the web page from a page other than any of the Falls pages, the modal should show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your condition is wrong.
You should compare variable with constant in every "sub condition".

```
if (document.referrer == "https://parks.com/parks/falls"
|| document.referrer == "https://parks.com/parks/events/falls"
|| document.referrer == "https://parks.com/parks/promotions/falls" 
|| document.referrer == "https://parks.com/parks/go-green/falls"
|| document.referrer == "https://parks.com/parks/info/falls") {
```

Maybe shorter:

```
const domains = ["https://parks.com/parks/cummins-falls", "https://parks.com/parks/events/falls", "https://parks.com/parks/promotions/falls", "https://parks.com/parks/go-green/falls", "https://parks.com/parks/info/falls"];
if (domains.includes(document.referrer)) {
```

for IE support

```
if (domains.indexOf(document.referrer) !== -1) {
```

Comment: No problem. If this was the answer that helped you the most, please select it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what your if clause actually returns:

```js
// prints "https://parks.com/parks/events/falls"
console.log(document.referrer == "https://parks.com/parks/cummins-falls" || "https://parks.com/parks/events/falls" || "https://parks.com/parks/promotions/falls" || "https://parks.com/parks/go-green/falls" || "https://parks.com/parks/info/falls")
```

This happens because with the OR operator (`||`), if the left hand expression cannot be coerced to `true` then it will return the expression on the right hand side.

So in your situation, `document.referrer == "https://parks.com/parks/cummins-falls"` evaluates to `false`, so it returns the result of `"https://parks.com/parks/events/falls"` which in Javascript evaluates to `true` in boolean operations, so it returns that expression in that OR operator and in the OR operators that follow.

See documentation on the [truthy concept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) for the specifics.

What you actually want:

```js
var falls = ["https://parks.com/parks/cummins-falls",  "https://parks.com/parks/events/falls", "https://parks.com/parks/promotions/falls", "https://parks.com/parks/go-green/falls", "https://parks.com/parks/info/falls"];

console.log(falls.indexOf(document.referrer) > -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is incorrect.
You should use this :

```
if (document.referrer == "https://parks.com/parks/cummins-falls" || document.referrer == "https://parks.com/parks/events/falls" || document.referrer == "https://parks.com/parks/promotions/falls" || document.referrer == "https://parks.com/parks/go-green/falls" || document.referrer == "https://parks.com/parks/info/falls") { 
    console.log("Don't Show Modal - coming from a Falls page", document.referrer);
} else {
    console.log("Show Modal - coming from some other Page", document.referrer);
}
```